# Prove that linear transformation f and g are related by $g=a*f$ for any real $a$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a finite dimensional vector space $V$ over $R$ and $f$ and $g$ are two linear transformations from $V$ to $R$ such that if $f(v)=0$ implies $g(v)=0$ Prove that $g=a*f$ for some a in $R$

Here is my solution :
let $v1$ and $v2$ be any elements of V , choose $x$ and $y$ in $R$ such that $f(x*v1+y*v2)=0$

Hence $$f(v1)/f(v2)=-1*(y/x)=g(v1)/g(v2)$$

where $v1$ and $v2$ are any elements of V , therefore we can say $g(v)=a*f(v)$

I just want to be sure whether my assumption of $v1$ and $v2$ being arbitrarily chosen is correct or not (Also sorry for bad formatting I am still new to this)

Comment: Is your $R$ an arbitrary field or the reals $\Bbb{R}$?

Comment: its the real field ℝ ,sorry I did not knew how to add the symbol

Comment: That's fine, it's \Bbb{R} .